# Using Enterprise Architect with Doxygen?

Tags: architecture, documentation, doxygen, enterprise-architect

I would like to combine Doxygen with custom pages and Enterprise Architect to export Diagrams so they can be used in the Doxygen documentation. The Doxygen documentation contains only hand written explanations (and auto generated class description), but in chapters about the architecture I would like to embed the EA pictures.

Is there any way to automatically export the images? Or is the manual export the only way of getting the diagrams out of EA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automated method to export Enterprise Architect diagrams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441479/automated-method-to-export-enterprise-architect-diagrams)

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to export diagrams.

- manually as you already found out.
- Using the document or HTML generator (the doc gen has a diagram only mode IIRC).
- And finally (my preferred method) is by using the API `Repository.GetProjectinterface.SaveDiagramImageToFile (string Filename)`